# Better way of handling complex form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

(this is a re-post - I deleted the first post because I think I posted really poorly).

I'm new to programming, and I'm trying to handle an ROR form that sends data to 4 different models/tables, and at this point I'm banging my head into the wall. In sum, the use case is that a teacher inputs the following into a form: an error, a corresponding correction, an abstraction of the error, an abstraction of the correction, some tags that describe the abstraction, and an explanation.

When I press submit, I'm not getting any errors on the screen, but when I look at the server, the only thing that gets submitted successfully is the original error and correction - I get an `unpermitted parameter: ec_abstractions` for the rest (ec_abstractions is the first level of nesting). I'm starting to think that I'm just going about the entire question wrongly.

The form looks like this (maybe should be split into multiple forms on the same view page?)

```
<%= form_for @ec_explanation do |ec_explanation_form| %>
  <% if @ec_explanation.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@ec_explanation.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this error-correction pair from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @ec_explanation.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%#= Insert here: all (or a single) q_response(s) that have not yet been added %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= ec_explanation_form.label :early_explanation %>
    <%= ec_explanation_form.text_area :early_explanation %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= ec_explanation_form.label :full_explanation %>
    <%= ec_explanation_form.text_area :full_explanation %>
  </div>
    <!--(this is just a test field for the "number_field" data type - I'm not convinced that we should input the stage like this)-->
  <div class="field">
    <%#= ec_explanation_form.label :stage %>
    <%#= ec_explanation_form.number_field :stage %>
  </div>

    <%= ec_explanation_form.fields_for :ec_abstractions do |ec_abstractions_form| %>

        <% if @ec_abstraction.errors.any? %>
            <div id="error_explanation">
              <h2><%= pluralize(@ec_abstraction.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this error-correction pair from being saved:</h2>

              <ul>
                <% @ec_abstraction.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                    <li><%= message %></li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
            </div>
        <% end %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= ec_abstractions_form.label :error_abstraction %>
        <%= ec_abstractions_form.text_field :error_abstraction %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= ec_abstractions_form.label :correction_abstraction %>
        <%= ec_abstractions_form.text_field :correction_abstraction %>
      </div>

      <%= ec_abstractions_form.fields_for :ec_pairs do |ec_pairs_form| %>

        <div class="field">
          <%= ec_pairs_form.label :error_phrase %>
          <%= ec_pairs_form.text_field :error_phrase %>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
          <%= ec_pairs_form.label :correction_phrase %>
          <%= ec_pairs_form.text_field :correction_phrase %>
        </div>

        <% end %>

      <%= ec_abstractions_form.fields_for :tags do |tags_form| %>

        <div class="field">
          <%= tags_form.label :tag, "Tag" %>
          <%= tags_form.text_field :tag %>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
          <%= tags_form.label :tag, "Tag" %>
          <%= tags_form.text_field :tag %>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
          <%= tags_form.label :tag, "Tag" %>
          <%= tags_form.text_field :tag %>
        </div>

      <% end %>
    <% end %>

     (Include javascript (or bootstrap) that will generate extra tag fields onclick of a 'plus' button)

  <div class="actions">
    <%= ec_explanation_form.submit 'Submit Correction' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I have the following models:

```
 class EcExplanation < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :abstractions_explanations_joins
      has_many :ec_abstractions, :through => :abstractions_explanations_joins
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :abstractions_explanations_joins
    end

    class AbstractionsExplanationsJoin < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :ec_explanation
      belongs_to :ec_abstraction
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :ec_abstraction
    end

    class EcAbstraction < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :ec_pairs
      has_many :tags_ec_abstractions_joins
      has_many :tags, :through => :tags_ec_abstractions_joins
      has_many :abstractions_explanations_joins
      has_many :ec_explanations, :through => :abstractions_explanations_joins
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags_ec_abstractions_joins
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :ec_pairs
    end

    class EcPair < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :response
      belongs_to :ec_abstraction
    end

    class TagsEcAbstractionsJoin < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :ec_abstraction
      belongs_to :tag
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :tag, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:tag].blank? }
    end

    class Tag < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :tags_ec_abstractions_joins
      has_many :ec_abstractions, :through => :tags_ec_abstractions_joins
    end
```

And the following controller code:

```
class CorrectionStoragesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @ec_explanations = EcExplanation.all
  end

  def show
  end


  def new
    @ec_explanation = EcExplanation.new
    @ec_abstraction = @ec_explanation.ec_abstractions.build
    @ec_pair = @ec_abstraction.ec_pairs.build
    3.times do
      @tag = @ec_abstraction.tags.build 
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @ec_explanation = EcExplanation.create(ec_explanation_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @ec_explanation.save
        format.html { redirect_to new_correction_storage_path, notice: 'Correction storage was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @ec_explanation }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @ec_explanation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @ec_explanation.update(ec_explanation_params)
        format.html { redirect_to new_correction_storage_path, notice: 'Correction was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: new_correction_storage_path }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @ec_explanation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @ec_explanation.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to correction_storages_url, notice: 'Correction was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end



  private

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def ec_explanation_params
      params.require(:ec_explanation).permit(:early_explanation, :full_explanation, ec_abstractions_attributes: [:id, :error_abstraction, :correction_abstraction, ec_pairs_attributes: [:id, :error_phrase, :correction_phrase], tags_attributes: [:id, :tag]])
    end
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will want to compare the parameters in `log/development.log` against what is permitted by `CorrectionStoragesController#ec_explanation_params`.

The error

> unpermitted parameter: ec_abstractions

means that [Strong Parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) rejected the parameter `ec_abstractions` because that is not in your whitelist.  To have the form submit a parameter called `ec_abstractions_attributes` you need to set up [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#configuring-the-model) in your EcExplanation model.

When your form has nested attributes like:

```
<%= form_for @ec_explanation do |ec_explanation_form| %>
  ...
  <%= ec_explanation_form.fields_for :ec_abstractions do |ec_abstractions_form| %>
    ...
```

Then you need:

```
class EcExplanation < ApplicationRecord
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ec_abstractions
```

Comment: The problem was that I was accepting nested attributes for the join model between ec_abstractions and ec_explanations, but I was only doing that because I had already tried the other way... or so I thought... anyways,  thanks! Not sure if this is the appropriate place to ask, but now I'm getting 2 error messages displayed on the screen: "ec abstractions ec pairs response must exist", and "ec abstractions ec pairs ec abstraction must exist". What should I go learn about in order to fix this? (no need to tell me the answer, just point me in the right direction :) )

Comment: nvm - it must have to do with belongs_to relationships. I'll figure out a way to add the belongs_to part first - I guess I'll have to not create all the parameters at once, although that would entail getting rid of strong parameters. Interesting.

Comment: What solved the problem for me was to make some of the `belongs_to` relationships optional by adding 'optional: true' after. I'm not sure if this will cause problems down the road - I guess I'll find out.